# Como verificar se o vetor de um registro está vazio em C

Tags: c, array, c++, struct

Eu tenho este registro:

```
typedef struct{
    char nome[200], telefone[200], email[200];
} Agenda;

Agenda contato;

Agenda vetor[300];
```

E quero imprimir somente os registros que possuem dados:

```
int lista_contatos(void){
    printf("========== Contatos ==========\n");

    for(i=0;i<300;i++){

        if(vetor[i].nome == NULL){
          printf("Contatos Listados.");
          main();  
        }else{
            printf(sizeof(vetor[i].nome));
            printf("Nome: %s \n",vetor[i].nome);
            printf("Telefone: %s \n",vetor[i].telefone);
            printf("Email: %s \n",vetor[i].email);
            printf("________________________\n");


        }       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta não dá detalhes e não coloca partes importantes para ajudar com mais propriedade, inclusive porque pode ter erros na parte não mostrada (há indícios que tem erros), mas em essência na forma apresentada, que não parece ideal, tem que criar um padrão, na hora que cria o vetor deve inicializar todos os elementos com um valor inválido, pode ser por exemplo colocar um nulo (`\0`) nas três *strings* em todos os elementos, isso indica  que não um dado válido. Tem que garantir que se um dado for entrado não pode ser vazio, tem que ter pelo menos um espaço. Aí na hora de acessar verifica o tamanho da *string*, se for 0 é porque o elemento está vazio.

Pode estar pensando que não precisa inicializa os 3 assim, e de fato para o que pede na pergunta só precisa um deles, mas para deixar em ordem em todos os casos é melhor fazer nos 3, não use algo sem inicializar.

Como optou por um *array* dentro da estrutura não tem um ponteiro e não faz sentido usar o `NULL`, até pode mas para verificar se o primeiro caractere da *string* é nulo, que é o que eu indiquei fazer acima, aí faria:

```
if (vetor[i].nome[0] == NULL) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/IsEmpty.c).